# How to solve the error << TqdmKeyError: "Unknown argument(s): {'delay': 2}" >> when downloading sentinel data using the sentinelsat API in Python?

Tags: api, satellite, sentinelsat, sentinel3

I am trying to download Sentinel-3 data using the sentinelsat API for Python. When running the code, I am getting the following error:

""

TqdmKeyError("Unknown argument(s): " + str(kwargs)))

TqdmKeyError: "Unknown argument(s): {'delay': 2}".

""

Any idea how to solve it?

The products I am trying to download: Sentinel-3 level 2 Land Surface temperature (SL_2_LST). Sensing period: 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31

I am using Spyder with Python 3.7. Below is my full code

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date

api = SentinelAPI("myusername", "mypassword", "https://apihub.copernicus.eu/apihub")


# Converting Date intel format  
initialDate = "2020-01-12"
date_in = "{}{}{}".format(initialDate[0:4], initialDate[5:7], initialDate[8:] )

finalDate = "2020-12-31"
date_end = "{}{}{}".format(finalDate[0:4], finalDate[5:7], finalDate[8:] )

# Loading the area of interest
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson(r"C:\Users\cad\Desktop\coding\map.geojson"))

# Launching the download
products = api.query(footprint,
                     platformname = "sentinel-3",
                     producttype = "SL_2_LST___",
                     date = (str(date_in), str(date_end)) 
                     )

 folder = r"C:\Users\cad\Desktop\coding\results" #path to save the files

 api.download_all(products, folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. I solved it by updating the tqdm package to version 4.59

```
pip install tqdm==4.59
```